# Hibernate / JBoss - "Service jboss-as has a circular dependency" on new Configuration()

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss7.x

When trying to get an Hibernate session opened, the part of the code that initializes the new Hibernate configuration breaks with the "Service jboss-as has a circular dependency" exception.

Calling the same code from a console application works correctly.

Tried both Hibernate 4.1.3 and 4.0.1 which is packed with JBoss 7.1, but getting the same error.

If anyone could nudge me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
```

JBoss output:

```
...
11:30:00,482 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 3324ms - Started 173 of 250 services (76 services are passive or on-demand)
11:30:00,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "JBCXFRS.war"
11:30:10,903 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class hr.spi.rs.MyApplication
11:30:24,081 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
11:30:24,144 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.3.Final}
11:30:24,213 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
11:30:24,233 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
11:30:24,432 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
11:30:24,437 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
11:30:24,825 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: 
11:30:25,466 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
11:30:25,473 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1
11:30:25,479 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
11:30:25,488 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000401: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://MyDbServer;databaseName=MyDatabase]
11:30:25,496 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
11:30:38,571 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
11:30:38,837 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
11:30:38,897 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
11:30:39,868 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
11:30:40,289 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS, service jbosgi.xservice."javax.naming.InitialContext", service jbosgi.xservice."javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactoryBuilder", service jboss.deployment.unit."JBCXFRS.war".CLEANUP] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.TransactionManager] 

11:30:40,303 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.jboss.msc.service.CircularDependencyException: Service jboss-as has a circular dependency
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After removing the name parameter in the session-factory portion of hibernate.cfg.xml, everything starts working without the "circular dependency" error.

I don't know why it has any problems with running this, or how is someone supposed to deduce that from the cryptic JBoss exception.

Posting it as answer in hope it saves someone a day of pulling hair.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="">
        ...
```

Changed to:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        ...
```

Comment: Wow - what a joke. So far, not impressed at all by JBoss 7. (And this crappy old application doesn't even rely on Hibernate, so I'm still screwed.) Time to switch servers...

Comment: I used JBoss primarily because of it's distributed transactions support (i.e. Arjuna is bundled in it), which works rather well. Also, when it runs - it runs; it's quite a stable server from my experience.